# Trying to Count specific items in QUERY

Tags: sql, count

I currently am returning a table that looks like this:

```
Country  Result
------   -----
Japan    sunk
Japan    sunk
USA      ok
USA      ok
```

with country and result being the column names

Id like to know how many times japan and sunken show up? So the resulting query I am trying to achieve is:

```
country      numSunk
-------      ------
Japan        2
USA          0
```

I've tried grouping or doing a where result="sunk" but I keep getting errors. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...that only appears to return Japan and 2. I still need to get USA 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS sunk
FROM table
WHERE result = "sunk"
GROUP BY country
```

Edit: if you want 0-rows then you can do:

```
SELECT country, SUM(IF(result = "sunk", 1, 0)) AS sunk
FROM table
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: This query will only return a single row: [Japan, 2], as no USA rows match the filter criteria.

Comment: Hmmm...that only appears to return Japan and 2. I still need to get USA 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT country, COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'sunk' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as numSunk
FROM myTable
GROUP BY country
```

The count will only be incremented when the result is 'sunk'.

Comment: @Guvante:  No, that won't work.  We need to use NULL when result <> 'sunk' so that the count is not incremented.  If we were to use 0 when result <> 'sunk' then the aggregate function would need to be SUM(), not COUNT().

Answer (score 0):

```
select country, count(country)
...
where result = "sunk"
group by country
```

Assuming this is a SQL query

Comment: This query will return only 1 row [Japan, 2].  Grouping is applied after filtering, so as no USA rows match the filter criteria, only the Japan rows will remain for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT country, count(*) numSunk
FROM table
WHERE result = 'sunk'
GROUP BY country
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT country, 0 
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE t.country = country AND result = 'sunk')
```

The first SELECT gives you all the countries with a sunk result along with the sunk count. The unioned second SELECT gives you all the countries that have no sunk result.